# Is it possible to get the exact (particular) information from openFDA?

Tags: api, data.gov, openfda, json

I am looking for just meta information from openFDA. Whenever I do a query I get all the information like meta, results. My requirement doesn't deal with results. We just care about metadata, because we only want "total" field information for our query. So we expect the JSON should only display metadata. That's how we can get the information easily without any performance issues.

Comment: By default, you should be getting 25 records. If you set the limit parameter to "1" then you will only get 1 record in addition to the metadata. I tried setting it to 0, but I seem to always get 1 record.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I knew that bydefault it gives me one record. But that record has meta and results. Whereas I want to return just a part of that json which is meta part.

Comment: Could you please give a real example of what information you want to retrieve? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time it's not currently possible to have the API return only the meta section. You can, as others have pointed out, restrict the API to return only one record along with the meta section. Let us know if this proves to be a problem for your use case.